# How to run c.vim plugin for python files

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I would like to run the c.vim plugin for VIM for not just c/cpp files but also for python files. I have already made all the custom templates for python.

When I create a new python file the c.vim does insert the automatic header that I have in the python template. However the shortcuts dont seem to work.

I am not able to figure out what else needs to be set to make it work.

Thank You for the help.

Comment: Do you mean the standard ftplugin, or maybe [this](https://github.com/WolfgangMehner/vim-plugins/blob/master/plugin/c.vim) one? For the latter, extensions are hard-coded in `s:C_SourceCodeExtensions` script-local variable, and there are no python extensions, of course. Do you need `c.vim` just for snippets?

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov Yes. The C.vim plugin you provided the link for. I love that we can put in code snippets. I just want to use a single tool for both CPP and python. Is there an alternative?

Comment: @theCuriousOne, you'd better find a more generic snippet/template expander plugin. There are plenty, and they won't be restricted to one language only. However, the syntax and the key that triggers the expansion won't be the same as the one you're currently using. See http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Automated_Text_Insertion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to make snippets for both C and Python file types using [`neosnippet`](https://github.com/Shougo/neosnippet.vim) plugin.

[Install](https://github.com/Shougo/neosnippet.vim#installation) the plugin and [configure](https://github.com/Shougo/neosnippet.vim#configuration) the key mappings:

```
imap <C-k> <Plug>(neosnippet_expand_or_jump)
smap <C-k> <Plug>(neosnippet_expand_or_jump)
```

You might want to use [Honza's snippets](https://github.com/honza/vim-snippets) as well as your own:

```
let g:neosnippet#snippets_directory = [ '~/.vim/bundle/vim-snippets/snippets',
      \ '~/.vim/my-neosnippets' ]
```

Create `~/.vim/my-neosnippets/python/python.c.snippets` file with custom snippets, for instance:

```
snippet [
  [${1}]
```

Then create a symbolic link to this file:

```
├── c
│   └── c.python.snippets -> ../python/python.c.snippets
└── python
    └── python.c.snippets
```

Now you can use `python.c` file type for Python files:

```
# vim: ft=python.c
```

And `c.python` file type for C files:

```
/* vim: set ft=c.python: */
```

If you don't like the idea to put modelines in every file, then you can use  the rule for all C and Python files:

```
au FileType,BufRead c set ft=c.python
au FileType,BufRead python set ft=python.c
```